# What is wrong with this "move" command?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I am trying to use command in Windows 10 as administrator to move 27,000 HTML files from one directory to another. When I use the command it reports that there is a syntax error. So what is wrong with the command?

```
h:\Recovery\Disk E>move /Y H:\Recovery\Disk E\*.html H:\Recovery\Disk E\! Documents\BROWSER Files\HTML Files\*.*
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Those directory names contain spaces. Try wrapping em in doublequotes like so:  `move /Y "H:\Recovery\Disk E\*.html" "H:\Recovery\Disk E\! Documents\BROWSER Files\HTML Files\"`. By wrapping an argument in doublequotes you ensure it is treated as a single argument, even if it contains spaces.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is the `*.*` at the end of the destination. That doesn't belong there, as you have already specified a destination directly where the HTML files (with whatever filenames they are) will be moved to.

Also, since the paths have spaces in them, in order for the command prompt to recognize them as 1 path you need to enclose them in quotes.

The command to use would be:
`move /Y "H:\Recovery\Disk E\*.html" "H:\Recovery\Disk E\! Documents\BROWSER Files\HTML Files\"`